# Following a 301 Redirect from an API in a React App

Tags: reactjs, redirect, oauth-2.0, react-router

I've written a custom ProtectedRoute component for my React app that redirects a user to a `/api/login` route on my Express API if that user is not authenticated. The `/api/login` route returns a 301 Redirect to the Auth0 Universal Login UI.

I know the `/api/login` route on the Express API works because I can hit it directly I get redirected to the Auth0 Universal Login (see the last code snippet).

I also know the ProtectedRoute is redirecting correctly because it redirects to `localhost:3000/api/login`, which is the correct route on the Express API to trigger the Auth0 Universal Login redirect.
What actually happens though is that `localhost:3000/api/login` shows up in the address bar but the redirect to the Auth0 Universal Login doesn't happen. That being said if I refresh the page then the redirect to the Universal Login UI works.

I'm not exactly sure why the Redirect returned from `/api/login` isn't followed in the Browser. I think it has something to do with how React is navigating to the route.

Here's the relevant code snippets. If more are needed let me know.

`Protected Route Component`

```js
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ISession {
    userId: string;
    role: string;
    details: any;
}

type RouteProps = {
    children?: JSX.Element;
    session: ISession;
    loading: boolean;
};

const ProtectedRoute = ({ session, children, loading }: RouteProps) => {
  const location = useLocation();

    if (loading) return null;
    else if (!!session.userId) {
      return children ? children : <Outlet />;
  }
    else {
      return <Navigate replace to="/api/login" state={{ redirectTo: location.pathname }} />;
  }
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

`How the ProtectedRoute Component is used with React Router`

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/home';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import { SessionContext } from './context/SessionContext';
import ProtectedRoute from './middleware/protectedRoute';
const App = () => {
  const { session, loading } = useContext(SessionContext);

  console.log('Session', session);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoute loading={loading} session={session} />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/dne" element={ <p>Stuff</p> } />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

*NOTE: I'm excluding the code from the SessionContext component for brevity. Since the user isn't able to login because the redirect to the Auth0 Universal Login UI doesn't work no session is ever created.*

`The "/api/login" route handler on the Express API`

```js
const login = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { redirectTo } = req.query;
  const domain = config.get('auth0.domain');
  const clientId = config.get('auth0.clientId');
  const host = config.get('host');


  // These 301 Responses are the Redirect to Auth0's Universal Login UI
  if (redirectTo) {
    const encodedRedirect = base64.urlEncode(redirectTo as string); // A Custom Base64 encoder that is URL Safe
    res.status(301).redirect(`${domain}/auth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${host}/api/auth/callback&state=${encodedRedirect}`)
  } else {
    res.status(301).redirect(`${domain}/auth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${host}/api/auth/callback`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Where does your `ProtectedRoute` actually render the protected route/content? Is your question about your frontend logic, or your backend logic? What Auth0 logic are you referring to? Please edit the post to include a complete and comprehensive [mcve]. It is unclear what you are asking for help with specifically.

Comment: @DrewReese My question is about the frontend logic. I know the API returns a redirect to the Auth0 Universal Login UI but when the React App navigates to the `/login` API route the redirect to the Auth0 Universal Login flow isn't followed.

Comment: Can you include all relevant code you are working with in your question? There is no `"/login"` or `"/api/*"` routes being rendered. Where is the redirect to the Auth0 logic? Also, like I said, the `ProtectedRoute` component doesn't appear to render the `children` prop or an `Outlet` for the nested routes.

Comment: To my understanding this is the code I am working with. Unless you want me to provide the entire code base which I cannot do I'm not sure what else you'd want besides some basic express routing logic which I know is not the problem.

I fixed the `ProtectedRoute` so it renders the Children or `Outlet`. 

the `/api/login` route is the very last code snippet which is where the redirect to the Auth0 logic happens.

Comment: So your app isn't rendering anything on a `"/api/login"` route? If the last snippet is where you are redirecting this is not your frontend code. I don't know what you are trying to ask about and I don't know why your frontend code is trying to navigate to a backend API endpoint. Perhaps this is the issue, navigating to a path the code isn't rendering a route for?

Answer (score -1):

It's not really an answer for what is going on but it is a solution.

The problem was `<Navigate to="/api/login" />` would cause React to Rerender the page and would change the URL in the address bar, but it would not cause the browser to make a `GET` request to the new address.

To solve this I just overwrote the `window.location.href` with `/api/login` in the `ProtectedRoute` component.

Here's the new version of the ProtectedRoute component.

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ session, children, loading }: RouteProps) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  if (loading)
    return null;

  if (!!session.userId) {
    return children ? children : <Outlet />;
  }
  else {
    window.location.href = '/api/login';
    return <Navigate replace={true} to='/api/login' />
  }
};
```

Comment: So I guess the misunderstanding was that `react-router-dom` doesn't make page requests to a server. It handles routing/navigation entirely client-side, and you were wanting to navigate to an external (*to your app*) route/path/URL/etc... to effect a page request to the server so the server could return a 301 to redirect the browser to the Auth0 portal.

Comment: That is correct